# What is the right way to save data from a list view?

Tags: ios, callback, react-native

I have a SearchPage component that performs a query and then displays the results in a list view. The user then selects which of the results that they want by tapping on them. This saves them to an array in the SearchResults component.

As seen in the code below, the 'displayWords' method is called when the results are returned. It pushes a new view on the stack, SearchResults, sets the right button to "Save", and attaches a function to be called which wants to save the data.

```
    class SearchPage extends Component {

    displayWords(words) {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        title: 'Results',
        component: SearchResults,
        rightButtonTitle: 'Save',
        onRightButtonPress: () => {this.props.navigator.pop();
                                   this.props.save()},
        passProps: {listings: words}
      });
      this.setState({ isLoading: false , message: '' }); 
   }
```

So here is the question, how do I get the items from the array in the SearchResults component into the callback? Or to the SearchPage? Or is there another pattern that I should be following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question!

Philosophically speaking, the whole navigator and navigation stack concept kind of breaks the React-y dataflow. Because if you could render the `SearchResults` component simply as a subcomponent of `SearchPage`, you'd just make the selected search results be part of the `SearchPage` state and pass them into `SearchPage` as props. `SearchPage` would also get a callback to notify `SearchResults` whenever a search result was toggled.

Alas, with the navigator being what it is, you're going to have to duplicate the state.

```
    displayWords(words) {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        title: 'Results',
        component: SearchResults,
        rightButtonTitle: 'Save',
        onRightButtonPress: () => {this.props.navigator.pop();
                                   this.props.save()},
        passProps: {listings: words, onWordToggle: this.onWordToggle}
      });
      this.setState({ isLoading: false , message: '' }); 
   }

   onWordToggle(word) {
     // add or remove 'word' from e.g. this._selectedWords; no need for
     // this.state because re-rendering not required
   }
```

while `SearchResults` would maintain the list of selected words in its `this.state` and simply notify `this.props.onWordToggle` whenever a word is added or removed.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: One correction: I believe it should be a colon instead of an equal sign in passProps. So `onWordToggle: this.onWordToggle`

Comment: Actually because of the dynamic scope in JavaScript it needed to be: `onWordToggle: this.onWordToggle.bind(this)`

Comment: Yes, you're right: colon, not equal sign! I fixed my comment.

Comment: As for binding `this.onWordToggle`: if you're using `React.createClass`, it should've been auto-bound for you. If you're using ES6 classes, though, then you'll have to bind it yourself.

Comment: Oh I just re-read your example, you're using ES6 classes. So yeah, you'll have to bind yourself.